# read filename from post method using prolog

Tags: html, prolog

I created a HTML form to browse a csv fil. in 'analyse.prolog' i need a prolog code to get the file name to put it as input to loadCSV function (for example i shlould get : "file.csv"  and i will call loadCsv("file.csv");. Can you help me?
This is my form code:

```
<form name='F' 
      action='analyse.prolog' 
      method='POST' 
      enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <label>Fichier : </label>
  <input type="file" 
         name="fname" 
         style="color:rgb(51,153,255); 
                border-color:rgb(100,153,0); 
                border-style:solid;" 
         size="200px" >
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" class="button" value="Analyser" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the SWI-Prolog web infrastructure, obtaining the file name is easy with the following steps:

## Define an HTTP handler

In your case, you can use for example:

```
:- http_handler(root('analyse.prolog'), handle_upload, []).
```

This invokes `handle_upload/1`, with the HTTP request as argument, when the form is submitted.

## Read the data and pass it along

`handle_upload/1` could start as follows:

```
handle_upload(Request) :-
        http_read_data(Request, Data, [on_filename(file_upload)]),
        ...
```

Where `file_upload/N+3` is automatically invoked when parsing this form, and could look like this:

```
file_upload(Stream, name_content(Name,Content), Options) :-
        option(filename(Name), Options),
        read_string(Stream, _, Content).
```

Note the additional arguments that are automatically added in this case. In particular, the **file name** is available in the passed `Options`. We read the file contents, and pass back a structure of the form `name_content/2`.

## Use the file name

This construction makes the file name available in the continuation of `handle_upload/1`. Thus, the definition could continue as follows:

```
handle_upload(Request) :-
        http_read_data(Request, Data, [on_filename(file_upload)]),
        option(fname(name_content(Name,Content)), Data),
        ...
```

Here, `fname` is the **HTML name** you assigned to this input field, and `name_content/2` contains the passed **file name** and file contents.

A more complete example is available from [`FileUpload.txt`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/howto/http/FileUpload.txt).